# Problems installing unetbootin on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ppa, repository, unetbootin

i have run

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gezakovacs/ppa
```

and get the following result with the last 4 lines giving errors:-

```
gpg: keyring `/tmp/tmp8k7uho4o/secring.gpg' created
gpg: keyring `/tmp/tmp8k7uho4o/pubring.gpg' created
gpg: requesting key FC91AE7E from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com
gpg: /tmp/tmp8k7uho4o/trustdb.gpg: trustdb created
gpg: key FC91AE7E: public key "Launchpad PPA for Geza Kovacs" imported
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:               imported: 1  (RSA: 1)
gpg: keyblock resource `/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/gezakovacs_ubuntu_ppa.gpg': file open error
gpg: no writable keyring found: eof
gpg: error reading `/tmp/tmp8k7uho4o/pubring.gpg': general error
gpg: import from `/tmp/tmp8k7uho4o/pubring.gpg' failed: general error
```

Many thanks for any help

Adding screen outputs as requested

```
$ sudo apt update
[sudo] password for kerry: 
Get:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/gezakovacs/ppa/ubuntu xenial InRelease [17.5 kB]
Get:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease [102 kB]
Err:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/gezakovacs/ppa/ubuntu xenial InRelease
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY D45DF2E8FC91AE7E
Err:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 40976EAF437D05B5  NO_PUBKEY 3B4FE6ACC0B21F32
Reading package lists... Done
W: GPG error: http://ppa.launchpad.net/gezakovacs/ppa/ubuntu xenial InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY D45DF2E8FC91AE7E
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/gezakovacs/ppa/ubuntu xenial InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: GPG error: http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 40976EAF437D05B5  NO_PUBKEY 3B4FE6ACC0B21F32
E: The repository 'http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

For David Foerster:-

```
$ apt-key list
/etc/apt/trusted.gpg
--------------------
pub   1024D/7FAC5991 2007-03-08
uid                  Google, Inc. Linux Package Signing Key <linux-packages-keymaster@google.com>
sub   2048g/C07CB649 2007-03-08

pub   4096R/D38B4796 2016-04-12
uid                  Google Inc. (Linux Packages Signing Authority) <linux-packages-keymaster@google.com>
sub   4096R/640DB551 2016-04-12 [expires: 2019-04-12]
```

and

```
ls -l /etc/apt/trusted.gpg*
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4171 Jan 15 07:13 /etc/apt/trusted.gpg
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1203 Jan 15 07:13 /etc/apt/trusted.gpg~
```

and

```
awk '$2=="/"' /proc/mounts
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root / ext4 rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered 0 0
```

Comment: You need to add no third party repository as Unetbootin is already in official Ubuntu repositories.

Comment: but if i try to install i get the following:-

Comment: @xangua if I try to just install i get following errors :-
Some packages could not be installed. 
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 unetbootin : Depends: p7zip-full but it is not installable
              Recommends: extlinux but it is not installable
              Recommends: unetbootin-translations but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Comment: Try running: sudo apt update, try again. What Ubuntu release are you using? Also please EDIT your question to add these terminal outputs.

Comment: are u just want burn image to USB drive with use `unetbootin` ?. If yes, i can give alternative solution other `unetbootin`.

Comment: Have you tried software center ? I can see an installation candidate for `unetbootin` there. If you just want to create an usb installer for any iso, you could try the inbuilt `Startup Disk Creator`. Hope it helps.

Comment: @Sourav Badami - I have tried that but it asks for a user and password that I have not given. Does not use my ubuntu user / pass so no idea what to enter for user / pass

Comment: Can you attach a screen shot of the window ?

Comment: @Sourav Badami - sorry cant attach screen shot because i cant login.  So cannot take screen shot - lets me boot from external usb drive but asks for user and pass that does not match my ubuntu install or any suggestions for standard ubuntu logins

Comment: @everyone - thanks so much for all your help.....

Comment: @David Foerster - added output from those commands to question. Thanks

Comment: Getting frustrated - tried Startup disk creator instead - worked ok but asks for user / pass that is unknown to me - maybe i try etcher - does anyone have install instructions

Comment: @David Foerster - sorry - new listings added to question - thanks again for your help

Comment: Maybe off topic as question was about unetbootin but i tried using startup disk creator and it has created bootable usb drive but it is asking for user / pass and it does not match my user / pass on ubuntu or any of the default passwords i have googled - any ideas please

Comment: Hi guys thanks for all your help but I have decided to give up on unetbootin.  I tried ryanw solution to install etcher - so easy

Comment: Only problem is whether to accept ryanw answer - I still cannot get unetbootin installed but etcher works and solves my real problem of creating a bootable usb hard drive - any advice....

Comment: I don't have an idea what causes the issue in your question but since all you appear to want is to make a bootable USB drive: possible duplicate of [How can I create a Windows bootable USB stick using Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/289559/how-can-i-create-a-windows-bootable-usb-stick-using-ubuntu)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you just want burn image easy to USB drive.

You can use [etcher](https://etcher.io/#downloads) as alternative `unetbootin`

i like this for simple UI

[image: etcher]

Comment: thanks - so easy to install but when i boot from hard drive it asks for user / pass and does not accept my ubuntu user pass - so i cannot login

Comment: do you mean default user & password for ubuntu? try username 'ubuntu' with an empty password. (note: input username without quotation marks just `ubuntu`)

Comment: I am accepting this as correct answer - it did not help me install unetbootin but gave me a much simpler alternative i did not know about - thank you all

Comment: Look at gparted partitions for the drive after using this... it totally screws the USB drive.

Answer (score 1):

**mkusb** can do it for you

- make a simple Ubuntu install drive (live-only)
- make a persistent live drive with Ubuntu
- wipe the drive (overwrite the first megabyte or the whole drive with zeros)
- restore the drive to a standard mass storage device

See the following link

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb

Install from the unstable repository, if you want the newest version

[mkusb/gui#Installation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/gui#Installation)