# Create Ubuntu Live on external HDD in Ext4 Partition

Tags: partitioning, live-usb, external-hdd

sorry if this is a silly question, I am new to Ubuntu.

I have an external HDD, and would like to create Ubuntu Live on a 20GB Ext4 partition of that system. I tried going to Disks, selecting the Ext4 partition and chose "Restore Disk Image".

After selecting the .iso file, the dialog warned me that the Disk size was 5TB. Does that mean, that the disk image will overwrite the other partitions?

Thanks

Comment: Ah, I see my mistake. I chose the dialog option pertaining to the entire HDD at the top, instead of selecting options for the partition at the bottom left.

Thanks for your help! If done correctly, does this method create a working Ubuntu Live version?

Comment: I am relatively new to this but maybe can shed some light. Copying the iso to a partition will normally not boot. There are ways to make grub boot an iso but those need to be added into grub or a working installation. Go here. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/ISOBoot.  I recommend grml-rescueboot.  That has been great in the past.

Comment: Thanks! Do you have any experience with uNetbootin (https://unetbootin.github.io/)?

Comment: I have never used it.  Some have done so with great success.  One thing about the Ubuntu world is that there are usually about ten ways to skin the apple(can't use the other word or someone will jump on me in this forum:).  BUT when you get a solution that works post it back here for others.

Comment: Unetbootin is good for installing Live / Persistent Linux OS to a partition without overwriting the whole disk. However It might not write to your external HDD. The Hard Disk option is for making a temporary Frugal install to C drive, used for installing Ubuntu to that drive.

Comment: **It is easy enough to create a Full install to a partition on an external USB** using the "Something else" option. You can adapt the method in these instructions if you want a drive that boots on both BIOS and UEFI mode computers. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1217832/how-to-create-a-full-install-of-ubuntu-20-04-to-usb-device-step-by-step. Use GParted to create just the / and bios_grub and boot,esp partitions and don't format any existing partitions.

Comment: It is also possible to use a similar method to make your own Live / Persistent Ubuntu on an external HDD by adapting the following method: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1227221/simple-hand-made-persistent-usb-that-boots-either-bios-or-uefi/1227225#1227225

Comment: Does installing Ubuntu damage the external HDD? The last comment under this post https://askubuntu.com/a/872094/1046869 seems to imply as much.

Comment: @F6uWJTHhK8 An Ubuntu install to External HDD or SDD is the same as to Internal HDD or SDD and will create no more damage. Nowadays USB **flash drives** are trading reliability for low cost and speed. Instead of getting 10000 to 1000000 writes, some flash drives are getting less than 500 writes. I am still using a 13 year old Kingston Data Traveler as a Persistent USB.

Comment: @C.S.Cameron Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Persistent install to USB HD Partition

I have not encountered a tool for installing Live Ubuntu to an external data HDD/SSD without overwriting the data on it.

UNetbootin will do a frugal install to a HDD partition but only to C drive. The install is meant to be temporary and is used for installing Ubuntu.

It is possible to make a Full install of Ubuntu to Partitions on a data SSD or HDD using 'Something else" however most data disks have a  msdos partition table which makes it necessary to create a new EFI partition table to boot in UEFI mode. this destroys the data on the drive.

It is easy to make a Live Ubuntu Install to a partition on a USB HDD/SSD as long as Non-Persistent BIOS mode boot is acceptable.

- Boot a Live USB with target USB drive plugged in.
- Start GParted and Resize/Move existing partition to create 20GB unallocated space.
- Apply all operations.
- Create a New ext4 partition in this space.
- Apply all operations and exit GParted.
- Open Terminal and type `sudo -H nautilus`.
- Open the Ubuntu ISO file using Archive Manager.
- Extract the ISO to the new ext4 partition.
- In Terminal run:

  `sudo mount /dev/sdx2 /mnt`

  `sudo grub-install --boot-directory=/mnt/boot /dev/sdx`

Where sdx2 is the New ext4 partition and sdx is the target USB drive.

Edit Boot/grub/grub.cfg adding:

`set root=(hd0,2)`

after the "Try Ubuntu ..." line.

If you want persistence or to multiboot ISO files or ability to boot in either BIOS or UEFI, or do a Full install, etc. let me know and I will edit this answer

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation!